# Field theory and distributive law.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, binary-operations, associativity

How do any subset of a Field inherit the properties-commutativity,associativity and specially Distributive law over the same operationsas that of field?Is there any ***intuitive way*** to understand that how do a subset of a field automatically acquire distributive law over the same operations as of the field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that any subset of a field inherits those properties. For example if we take our field to be $K = \mathbb{Q}$ with the usual operations, then the set $\{6\}$ does not inherit the properties the operations on $K$ because it is not even closed under those operations.

However, if you require that your subset $R$ be a ring under the operations of $K$, then all the properties of the operations *do* descend to the operation on $R$. I think the most intuitive way to think about this is to think about the operations on $R$ as being the operations on $K$ with inputs restricted to $R$. Since the properties you mentioned (commutativity, associativity, etc.) are statements about the operations on $K$ for any possible inputs, they still hold when you restrict the inputs to $R$.

Comment: Worth emphasis: this holds only for $\rm\color{#c00}{universal}$ statements such as $\color{#c00}{\forall x,y}\!: x\cdot y = y\cdot x.\,$ It may fail otherwise, e.g. $\forall x\!\neq\! 0\ \exists y\!:\ x\cdot y = 1\,$ generally doesn't persist in subrings, i.e. a subring of a field needn't be a field.